# Steganography resistant to JPEG compression and manipulation

Tags: image, jpeg, steganography

I want to hide a small image data inside a much bigger image i.e. Image Steganography.

And want to make it resistant to JPEG compression/re-compression , manipulations etc.

I was wondering if there is some widely-used/standard algorithms/methods for this.

I came across many algorithms like F5 etc.
But they seem to be not resistant against re-compression.

Also as mentioned in some papers , the method which should resist JPEG compression usually have less capacity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does there exist a digital image steganography algorithm which would be resistant to image manipulation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799896/does-there-exist-a-digital-image-steganography-algorithm-which-would-be-resistan)

Comment: Are there such algorithms? Yes. Google Scholar is your friend here. The question, as currently formulated, is too broad and has too many correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like a QR code -- with as much error correction as possible. That's why blurry pictures, or bad camera hardware, still works with most QR codes (and also why some people are able to put logos in the middle of QR codes and still get them to scan).

Basically, you'll need to design some really good redundancy (as much as possible), and then test the image by running a gaussian blur on it (or compressing it).  There will always be a level where it won't work, but you'll have to play with that to find the best range for your business case.